# How can I add time to a date time data frame with unknown time zone

Tags: r, date, time, timezone, lubridate

I'm working with some date-time data that is offset from its correct time zone by 2 hours. It should be in East Africa Time, but I don't know what time zone it's set to in the raw data.

It seems easy enough to add 2 hours to the data. However, the tricky case is when I have a time near midnight because adding hours to this will put the date into the next day.

This is what I have:

```
df <- c ("09/11/2015 16:00", # 9th November 2015
         "09/11/2015 17:00",
         "09/11/2015 22:00")

parse_date_time(x = df, c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
```

I'd like something like this:

```
df2 <- c ("09/11/2015 18:00", # 9th November 2015
         "09/11/2015 19:00",
         "10/11/2015 00:00") # 10th November 2015
```

Comment: adding 2 hours does give you your expected output, right? `as.POSIXct(df, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") + 60 * 60 * 2`. Output can be `format`ted if needed. Or with `lubridate` , `dmy_hm(df) + hours(2)`

Comment: with lubridate you should be able to do `parse_date_time(x = df, c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) + hours(2)`

Comment: Ah that's great, I didn't realise it changed the date too. One issue is that the results are still in UTC

Comment: Got it, it's just `parse_date_time(x = df, c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), tz = "africa/dar_es_salaam") + hours(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help in the comments it should be:

```
parse_date_time(x = df, c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), tz = "africa/dar_es_salaam") + hours(2)
```